# Login con Python, Inicia sesion sin comparar

Tags: python, login

Estoy haciendo un login en el backend con Python usando FastApi, cuando trato de comparar con el form_data, no me hace la comparación en incia sesión siempre.

Dejo el código;

```
@app.post("/login")
def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):

    consultaUser = conexion.execute(TablaUsers.select().where(form_data.username == TablaUsers.c.username and form_data.password == TablaUsers.c.password ))

    if not consultaUser:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")

    return {"access_token": form_data.username, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

Comment: Pues tiene pinta de que `consultaUser` tiene un valor que se considera _truthy_, incluso si no encuentra lo que busca en la base de datos. Para depurar yo imprimiría la variable `consultaUser` tras su iniciañización

Comment: Con el debugger? o imprimiedo?

Comment: Es más fácil con un simple `print()`, si tienes acceso a la consola (es decir, si no se está ejecutando por ejemplo en un contenedor detrás de un balanceador o algo así)

Comment: me aparece undifined y null

Comment: Las dos cosas? Como puede ser? Pon mejor `print(repr(consultaUser))` para ver la representación de lo que has recibido, que sospecho será una cadena, o una tupla de cadenas o algo así.

Comment: Null es lo que imprime, seguire investigando